# JavaScript - Return from anonymous function (varScope)

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

```
<script>
    var sample = function() {
        (function() {
            return "something"
        })();
        // how can I return it here again?
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to return the returned value from the anonymous function in the parent function again or do I need to use a defined function to get the returned value? Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, I'm dumb. Just put the `return` before the anonymous function and done. LOL.

Comment: Um, store the result of the self-execution in a variables, or just `return` it directly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just put the return statement at the point where you call the function.

```
<script>
    var sample = function() {
        return (function() {  // The function returns when you call it
            return "something"
        })();
    }
</script>
```