# How to return value javascript function from anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, anonymous-function

I am learning basic NodeJS and I have a problem.
How to return function value from anonymous function inside it
eg:

```
function blah() {
    message("blah blah", function(z) {
        var r = "blah blah";
        return r;
    });
}
var result = blah();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229767/javascript-return-from-anonymous-function-varscope

Comment: Is `message()` synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @Archer this is async method

Comment: In that case you can't do what you're trying to do above.  You'll need to look into handling responses from asynchronous methods.  The link from Matias will help you with that.